# UITableView headerview keeps repeating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am making an iPhone app. In this app I have a UITableView which has a UITableView header.  This is how my code looks like.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 308, 50)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sx_home_tablehead.png"]];
    self.tableViewAppointments.tableHeaderView = view;
```

And this is how it looks like on my iPhone

[image]
And this is what I want to achieve

[image]

Hope that anyone can help me !

Kind regards !

Comment: Add it as table view section header by implementing delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're specifying explicitly the frame of the view. You should not do a terrible hack like this. Use this piece of code instead:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = imgView;
```

Comment: this worked for me! but what must I do to get it like the screenshot above ?

Comment: @StefGeelen I suspect if you do this, you will get the expected result (provided the image is of the proper size).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it as a table view section header, you need to add it as follows,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 308, 50)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sx_home_tablehead.png"]];
 //or,
    UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sx_home_tablehead.png"]];
    return view;
}
```

You can define the height for header in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return height;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't set the table header view but a section header.

Comment: Yes, that's true. If he wants it to attach with table view section, this is the one he is looking for. Otherwise yours is the correct one.